# Device is not ready error on DriveInfo.DriveFormat

Tags: c#, driveinfo

i have that method that retrieve the removable devices information which are NTFS :

```
    private void getdriverinfo()
    {
        // get the usb flash driver
        foreach (DriveInfo driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && driveInfo.DriveFormat.Equals("NTFS"))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(driveInfo.Name);
            }
        }
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Removable Device Found , please plug in the USB drive and make sure it is in NTFS format and retry", "No Device Found!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Items.Count + " Removable Devices were found , please choose the device you want to protect");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the usb flash driver
        getdriverinfo();       
    }
```

This error occurs:

> System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIODriveError(String driveName, Int32 errorCode)
>
> at System.IO.DriveInfo.get_DriveFormat()
>
> at USB_Data_Protector.Form1.getdriverinfo()

This works fine on my laptop with no errors. When it's run on virtual pc or another pc, this error shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you check the following before you access the DriveFormat?  [IsReady Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx)

```
driveInfo.IsReady
```

Comment: Wow , it worked , but why ? maybe because it needed time to be ready or what ?

Comment: added the relevant link to that property